# Node.js transport data between scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, hapi.js

I am developing a node.js server in Hapi framework. I adopted RabbitMQ (amqp) to queue my tasks. Though, once a request is sent, instead of replying the request immediately, a message will be sent to Rabbit server where the actual function seats at as consumer. Then, the consumer should return the result to (request, reply) function and let the function reply it.

Now my solution is creating a variable in my worker file (where the amqp consumer located) and export it. Then in the index file (my main script with route handler), I import the variable. Once some request is received, it will send a message to RabbitMQ server and the server will change the variable. Then, back to index file, the script updates the variable's value and then reply it. Obviously, because of asynchronous, the program replies the result of previous request.

I did some research and found we are not supposed to sharing some variable between scripts. Does anyone have a solution? My objective is that I can put my amqp consumers in a script. Once I run the script, the consumers will be ready to receive any corresponding message. Then in my index file, once some request is received, it sends a message to RabbitMQ server. And then it should grabs the result of consumer and reply it.

Below is my code:

index.ts

```
import * as Joi from "joi";
import * as amqp from "amqplib/callback_api";
import * as waitUntil from "wait-until";

import * as repository from "./repository";
import * as worker from "./worker";

// defien variables from internal modules
let greeter = new repository.Greeter();

// register type
import {Register} from "../../interfaces";

// define amqp related stuff
let greeterReply = worker.greeterReply;

// helloWorld config including handler, validate and auth
export let register: Register = (server, options, next) => {
    server.route([
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/greeter",
        config: {
            handler: (request, reply) => {
                let q: string = "greeter";
                let requestQuery = request.query;
                let requestString = JSON.stringify(requestQuery);
                amqp.connect("amqp://192.168.0.31", (err, conn) => {
                    conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
                        ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
                        ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(requestString));
                    });
                });
                waitUntil(500, 10, function condition() {
                    greeterReply = worker.greeterReply;
                    return (greeterReply !== null);
                }, function done(result) {
                    reply(greeterReply);
                    greeterReply = null;
                });
            },
            validate: {
                query: {
                    name: Joi.string(),
                    age: Joi.number()
                }
            },
        }
    }
    ]);
    next();
};

register.attributes = {
    name: "greeter",
    version: "1.0"
};
```

worker.ts

```
// import external modules
import * as amqp from "amqplib/callback_api";

// import internal modules
import * as repository from "./repository";
import * as indexModule from "./index";

// defien variables from internal modules
let greeter = new repository.Greeter();

export let greeterReply = null;

amqp.connect("amqp://192.168.0.31", (err, conn) => {
    conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
        let q: string = "greeter";
        ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
        ch.consume(q, function (requestString)  {
            let newRequest = JSON.parse(requestString.content.toString());
            console.log("replied via amqp");
            let result: string = "how are you";
            result = greeter.helloWorld(newRequest.name, newRequest.age);
            console.log("the result is: ", result);
            greeterReply = result;
        }, {noAck: true});
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at plugins to encapsulate this type of thing.  Also use a callback in your worker function to trigger and control processing.  By using classes you could encapsulate the state of each request however if you are intending high throughput this may eventually become a problem.

Comment: If I use a callback function, I have to call the function in Index file right? This is not what I intend to do. I do have pretty many routes to deal with. Could you explain the plugin method in detail? How can I register amqp as plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require is a kind of RPC over RabbitMQ. It is supported by RabbitMQ, as shown here in the [tutorials here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html).

You can either implement it yourself using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) which you're already using, or you can use a specific module like [amqp-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp-rpc) to do it for you.

Comment: I believe that's the solution! Than you buddy. But, without using RPC, I notice my program (the codes above) works fine if I don't run worker in a terminal. It looks like the consumer runs as a child process when the publisher sends a message. Do you know the reason? @tbking

Comment: That's because you have imported the worker file, and that means you only need to run index file, and it will in run the worker file and invoke your worker itself.
Your code is like this that you don't need to run these files separately.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, do you think I still need to use RPC? If so, what benefit I can get?

Comment: Well, the benefit will be that your master and worker will be **completely decoupled** from each other. Right now your master depends on a file in the same directory called _worker.js_. If you rename the worker file, you have to change code in _index.js_ too.
While in RPC, they both are totally unaware of each other. There can be multiple workers too. Master doesn't need to know that. They can be placed at different systems connected through RPC over internet. So it's always good to use that. You've to decide if you want that.

Comment: Thank you @tbking! I already applied it. I can see the benefit.